# How to make a http post request for Uploading a file as well as sending json payload simultaneously

Tags: java, spring-boot, file

I have been trying to upload a file as well as send some data with it through Postman using springboot but for some reason, But I don't know whats happening it's not working, I have tried using `@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file and @RequestBody MyClass myClass`  in the method but it's not working , I have also used `@requestPart` annotation but it's not working

I am using the following code , but I donot know whats wrong with this?

```
@RestController
public class FileUpload {
    
    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public String register(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file , @RequestBody User 
user        
        String uploadDirectory = "myDirectory";

        if (file.isEmpty() || file == null) {
            return "file cannot be null or empty";
        }
        try {
            File dir = new File(uploadDirectory);
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdir();
            }
            String originName = file.getOriginalFilename();
            System.out.println(originName);

            File destination = new File(uploadDirectory + File.separator + originName);
            if(destination.exists()) {
                return "file with same name already exists";
            }else {
                file.transferTo(destination);
            }
            return "successfully file uploaded using userID : " + user.getUserid();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "upload failed";
        }                   
    }
```

Can I not perform both operations at same time, I think it should be possible?

Comment: Yes, its possible to perfom both file upload and json submission in the same request. You have some errors in your code where the request is not handlet correctly and the method is missing some annotations.

Comment: can you please provide what should i use here, and what kind of annotations should i use here

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use @RequestPart for both the file and the your json payload.

```
public String register(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file, @RequestPart("user") User user) {
your original code here ...

}
```

Comment: I did exactly as you said but its still not working it says that "org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.impl.InvalidContentTypeException: the request doesn't contain a multipart/form-data or multipart/mixed stream, content type header is application/json

Comment: try to change @`RequestPart  `to @`RequestParam` for both

Comment: Also make sure that the request you send from Postman matches the parameter names in the @RequestParam annotations and includes the file and user data accordingly